# Image from SD card to byte[]

Tags: android, image-processing, arrays

how can i get the byte[] of an image from android emulator SD card?

here's my current code:

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/test.jpg");
ImageView mImgView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

What i want is the byte format of the image how can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `ByteArrayOutputStream` then call `compress()` method of `Bitmap` so the contents of bitmap will be passed in `ByteArrayOutputStream` and converted to `byte[]`

```
public byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap b)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
```

To apply,

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

byte[] bitmapBytes = bitmapToByteArray(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Bitmap to byte[] like :

```
String imageInSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/Folder/" + filename + ".PNG";
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```